# How to use a list for combobox PYQT5

Tags: python, list, combobox, pyqt5

Hi I've declared my list

```
selecttime = ['7','8','9']
```

and I want to use a Combobox box by using the list that I've declared

```
    page.comboBox = QComboBox(page)

    page.comboBox.addItems("choose time", (selecttime))
    page.comboBox.activated[str].connect(self.onComboActivated)
```

This is my code I've input selecttime into the Combobox but the error persists!!!

Comment: `page.comboBox.addItems(["choose time", *selecttime])`

Comment: `comboBox.addItem('choose time')
comboBox.addItems(selecttime)`

Comment: Do you really want "choose time" as one of the options? What is supposed to happen if the user selects that option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not forming the general list correctly.

Change `page.comboBox.addItems("choose time", (selecttime))` to `page.comboBox.addItems(["choose time", *selecttime])`

As an option, you can do this:

```
selecttime = ['7','8','9']

print(["choose time", *selecttime])
```

---

```
['choose time', '7', '8', '9']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `list1` is a list of strings, then you can simply add them all at once using the [addItems](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#addItems) method:

```
self.comboBox_2.clear()
self.comboBox_2.addItems(list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the [documentation](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtwidgets/qcombobox.html#) it wants a list of strings to iterate through.

if you want to add "choose time" you can:

```
selecttime, ct = ['7','8','9'], ['choose time']
self.comboBoxWuTang.addItems(selecttime.extend(ct))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
page.comboBox.addItem("choose time")
page.comboBox.addItems(selecttime)
```